# Why this output get out with one delay?

Tags: verilog, delay, mux

I made 4_to_1 MUX with 2_to_1 MUX. I used `always` syntax. The output is delayed one time unit, but I don't know why. 
When I change the `always` condition of 4_to_1 MUX's module `sel` to `*`, it works well.  Why is this working?

```
module MUX_2_to_1 (
            a0,a1,sel,out);
input [3:0]a0;
input [3:0]a1;
input sel;
output reg [3:0]out;

always @(sel)
begin

    if (sel == 0)
        out <= a0;
    else if (sel == 1)
        out <= a1;
end
endmodule
```

*

```
    module MUX_4_to_1(
        x0,x1,x2,x3,sel,out);

input [3:0]x0;
input [3:0]x1;
input [3:0]x2;
input [3:0]x3;

input [1:0]sel;

output reg [3:0]out;

wire [3:0]w0;
wire [3:0]w1;


MUX_2_to_1 m0 (x0,x1,sel[0],w0);
MUX_2_to_1 m1 (x2,x3,sel[0],w1);

always @(sel)
begin
    if(sel[1] == 0)
        out <= w0;

    else if (sel[1] == 1)   
        out <= w1;

end



endmodule
```

*

```
`timescale 100ps/1ps

module Testbench_Mux;

reg [3:0]x0;
reg [3:0]x1;
reg [3:0]x2;
reg [3:0]x3;
reg [1:0]sel;

wire [3:0]out;

MUX_4_to_1 m0 (x0,x1,x2,x3,sel,out);


initial
begin


    x0 = 4'b0001; x1 = 4'b0010; x2 = 4'b0100; x3 = 4'b1000;
    #0  sel = 2'b00;
    #5  sel = 2'b01;
    #5  sel = 2'b10;
    #5  sel = 2'b11;
    #5 $stop;
end

endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not using recommended Verilog coding practices for combinational logic.  One problem is that you used an incomplete sensitivity list:

```
always @(sel)
```

Since there are 2 other signals, `w0` and `w1`, which are read in the `always` block, they must also be in the sensitivity list.  The verbose way to do this is:

```
always @(sel or w0 or w1)
```

The preferred way to do this is to use the compact `*` syntax:

```
always @(*)
```

This assures that the `always` block will be triggered when any change occurs to any signal read in the block.

Another issue is that you should always use blocking assignments for combinational logic.  There is ample documentation out there as to the reason. 
 Change `<=` to `=`:

```
always @(*)
begin
    if(sel[1] == 0)
        out = w0;
    else if (sel[1] == 1)   
        out = w1;
end
```

If you don't follow these recommendations, you get undesired simulation results.

You should change your `MUX_2_to_1` module as well.